# HTML Input - AngularJS - Doesn't display more than 3 digits

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, filter

When I enter a number of 4 digits (not counting decimals) or more into the input box it suddenly disappears from the number input box when I click out (blur). Could it be the currency filter that's doing it?

If i log it to the console the model is still keeping the value, it's just disappearing from the view.

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-2">
    <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
    <input type="number" step="any" min="0" class="form-control" id="promoSetupFee" data-ng-model="fees.setup.promo" data-ng-format-curr data-ng-blur="updateSetupTotal()">
</div>
```

---

```
crtPromoDir.directive('ngFormatCurr', ['$timeout', '$filter', function($timeout, $filter)
{
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            $timeout(function()
            {
                element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0), '', 2));
            });

            element.blur(function()
            {
                element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0), '', 2));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

EDIT: It seems HTML input of type number doesn't accept commas, is there any way I can remove commas from the directive I have?

EDIT:

```
$scope.updateSetupTotal = function()
{
    $scope.fees.setup.total = (parseFloat($scope.fees.setup.promo) || 0.00)+(parseFloat($scope.fees.setup.loc) || 0.00)+(parseFloat($scope.fees.setup.premium) || 0.00)+(parseFloat($scope.fees.setup.content) || 0.00);

    $scope.updatePromoTotal();
};
```

EDIT: Quick fix is to use type text for the input rather than number, but this means the models will now be strings rather than floats.

Comment: Highly unlikely that it is the currency filter. What is this function `updateSetupTotal()`?

Comment: See the EDITS I added.

Comment: Why are you using float for a dollar amount?

Comment: you should be using `ng-model` controller and updating the viewValue. Approach is wrong

Comment: I wasn't using the currency filter before so I forgot to remove those parseFloat functions which I'll do now.

Comment: He is using ng-model. I don't think that's the issue. Looks like it may be that updatePromoTotal() or whatever sets `fees.setup.promo`.

Comment: You don't have to use Strings for the models, you can set up getters/setters for the data.

Answer (score 0):

To remove commas from the string, do:

```
element.val($filter('currency')((element.val().replace(',','') || 0), '', 2));
```

Comment: This didn't do anything, same issue.

Comment: You asked, `It seems HTML input of type number doesn't accept commas, is there any way I can remove commas from the directive I have?` This removes commas from the the input. It addresses that question.

Comment: I understand, but for some reason when I blur out of the input box it is still making the value disappear.

Comment: See my answer, had to make a variation.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using a variation of alex's answer. Basically, since the `currency` filter adds commas, I have to remove them right after that filter is applied and before it's sent to the input box.

```
crtPromoDir.directive('ngFormatCurr', ['$timeout', '$filter', function($timeout, $filter)
{
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            $timeout(function()
            {
                element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0.00), '', 2).replace(',',''));
            });

            element.blur(function()
            {
                element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0.00), '', 2).replace(',',''));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

This allows me to keep the model an int and avoid having to use a string value.

Comment: Oh, you're using the filter to convert your string to numeric value? I don't necessarily agree with that approach but if it works for you, then I guess that fixes it. I'd personally do my own logic to convert to Numeric and use filter only for display.

Comment: Well the HTML input number input type is an `int`. If I log to the console the value of the input box it shows an int, not a string like a text type. Or am I confusing things here?

Comment: [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter): _A filter formats the value of an expression for display to the user. They can be used in view templates, controllers or services and it is easy to define your own filter._ A way you can check if it is a number or not is to wrap the suspected value in, `isNaN(  value  )`. If that returns true then it is "Not a Number". If it returns false, then it is a number

Comment: I did `console.log(isNaN(element.val()));` on blur before the filter is applied and got `false`.